# Where exactly in the OSI model does TLS/SSL belong

Tags: tls, network, protocols

I am trying to understand where exactly SSL/TLS sits in OSI model. If I look at [this answer on StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/where-does-ssl-encryption-take-place),

> While all network models are imperfect, this question can only be
>   answered by looking at what SSL (TLS really) does. (1) On top of a
>   reliable network stream (TCP at OSI layer 4) it provides an encrypted
>   bidirectional stream and (almost always) guarantees the identity of
>   the server and (optionally) the client. The authenticating client can
>   be a process, user or some other entity which can properly answer the
>   required authentication challenges.
>
> TLS means Transport Layer Security. However since it does implement
>   session identity, integrity, start up, tear down and management it
>   very much belongs in the session layer. The Wikipedia page states that
>   this belongs to the OSI presentation layer. This is probably wrong.
>   The presentation layer is more concerned with marshalling data into
>   non-network-dependent formats and interpreting it on the host side
>   through the appropriate application.
>
> At-rest encryption (say in a database field or email message) might be
>   a candidate for the presentation layer, but I would suggest that it's
>   closer to a form of OS or application security.
>
> So in reality TLS is mostly session-layer as it provides
>   point-to-point session security for the transport (TCP). In other ways
>   it provides authentication functions which are clearly application
>   layer (OS, utility or user app).
>
> So it's a lot of layer 5 and a little of layer 7.

It explains how it sits on layers 7 and 5.

But [these slides explaining BEAST attack on SSL/TLS](https://pt.slideshare.net/danrlde/20120418-luedtke-ssltlscbcbeast) says its on layer 6,

[image]

[image]

Can someone please explain (if possible with a diagram) where exactly SSL/TLS happens?

Comment: There is no "exact", which is why you are getting different answers.

Answer (score 0):

The OSI model is defined in the ITU document [X.200](http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?id=T-REC-X.200-199407-I!!PDF-E&lang=e&type=items).

The document doesn't expressly mention encryption.

**Section 7.2.4 (Functions within the Presentation Layer**

*Item b* says

> representation of the abstract syntax chosen by the application-entities in the transfer syntax negotiated or
>   renegotiated, including format and special purpose transformations (for example, data compression);

This definition is the best fit I can find for what I would describe as TLS doing. I would say TLS is Layer 6.

Comment: TLS is applied on data stream. And is not considered a network protocol even though TLS has its own state machine and request/reply headers.